# ruby find value in array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes that I need to sort through to find a value.  Once the value is found the whole article hash should be returned and not just the one value.

```
@articles = [{:"xy.id"=>["ID_100"], :"xy.url"=>["http://websiteA.com"], :TestQuestions=>["A//B/C//D, apple"]}, {:"xy.id"=>["ID_200"], :"xy.url"=>["http://websiteB.com"], :TestQuestions=>["E//F/G//H, orange"]}]
```

what I've tested with so far

```
# doesn't find the key
@articles.each do |article|
  test_article = article.key?("xy.id")
  puts test_article
end
```

prints nothing

```
@articles.each do |article|
  test_article = article.select {|k| k["xy.id"] == "ID_200"}
  puts test_article
end
```

prints the keys, not sure how to return the entire article hash entry though

```
@articles.each do |article|
  doc.each do |key, value|
     puts key
  end
end
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you are looking for a `value` in one of the hashes, but in your example you think you should have matched a key. You don't match any key because you are searching for a string and all keys in all hashes are symbols. If, by "value", you mean an object, you should say "object". If so, can that object be a key or a value? Can it be in a nested object? For example, could you be searching for `"ID_100"`? Could one hash be `{ :a=>1, :b=>[:c, [:d, :e]] }` and you are searching for `:c` or `:d`? Please clarify by editing (even though you've selected an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` would do it:

```
@articles.find { |article| article[:"xy.id"] == ["ID_100"] }
#=> {:"xy.id"=>["ID_100"], :"xy.url"=>["http://websiteA.com"], :TestQuestions=>["A//B/C//D, apple"]}
```

Things to notice:

- the key is a *symbol*, so a `:` is needed
- the value is an *array*, so you need to surround the value with `[]`

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm getting `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)` I think it's because the hash has strings in it?

Comment: @random_user_0891 Hmm, you should'nt get any error, are you sure that you tried with the exact same code (both on your question and my answer)?

Comment: sorry about that, I had a typo.  works great, thanks!